# Windows thread pool, 'PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

**VC6.0, Win10, C++.**

When I declare a thread pool callback function

```
VOID CALLBACK ProcessHook(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE instance, PVOID lParam);
```

I compile it and get an error

> error C2065: 'PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE' : undeclared identifier

I have included `Windows.h`

**code**

```
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 VOID CALLBACK ProcessHook(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE instance, PVOID lParam);
```

**result**

```
    c:\users\jasey\windows-program\keyboardhook\keyboardhook.h(33) : 
    error C2065: 'PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\jasey\windows-program\keyboardhook\keyboardhook.h(33) : 
    error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'instance'
    c:\users\jasey\windows-program\keyboardhook\keyboardhook.h(33) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
```

Comment: It seems you have not installed a proper Win SDK. Why are you using so extremely old VC 6.0, that is 20 years old?

Comment: i have read the windows doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-trysubmitthreadpoolcallback  and it says that only require `Windows.h`. What's the name of the SDK? Using VC6.0 because it is lightly~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Windows SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and then install or install it [via Visual Studio](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads).

From WiKi:

> **windows.h** is a Windows-specific header file for the C and C++ programming languages which contains declarations for all of the
>   functions in the Windows API, all the common macros used by Windows
>   programmers, and all the data types used by the various functions and
>   subsystems.

You can find it under this path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um if you install SDK version of 17134.

Here the SDK represent Windows Software Development Kit. After installation, You will see "Windows Software Development Kit-Windows 10.0.17134.12" in Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features, for example.

Windows SDK provides header files(like windows.h), libraries and tools to help you to development your windows applications.