# TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, winapi

**env**

Win10, VC6.0

**question**

When I use windows default thread pool to submit workers,
It compile error. I use VC6.0, and having included `Windows.h`
but it can't find the function. Please help me.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"

int KeyMap[128];



int main()
{
    ScriptHeadTail* pSht = (ScriptHeadTail*)KeyMap[101];
    if (pSht != NULL){
        TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback(ProcessHook, (LPVOID)(pSht->head), NULL);
    }

    Sleep(1000);

    return 1;
}


VOID CALLBACK ProcessHook(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE instance, PVOID lParam)
{
    ExecuteScript* pScript = (ExecuteScript*)lpParam;
    while (pScript != NULL){
        switch (pScript->type)
        {
            case KEYBOARD :
            {
                printf("send key : %d\n", pScript->value);
                break;
            }
            case LBUTTON :
            {
                printf("left button down : %d\n", pScript->value);
                break;
            }
            case RBUTTON :
            {
                break;
            }
            case IDLE :
            {
                Sleep(pScript->value);
                break;
            }
        }
        pScript = pScript->next;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct ExecuteScript
{
    int type;
    int value;
    ExecuteScript* next;
};

struct ScriptHeadTail
{
    ExecuteScript* head;
    ExecuteScript* tail;
};

BOOL Init(LPCSTR configFile);
BOOL LoadConfigFile(const char* configFile);
VOID CALLBACK ProcessHook(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE instance, PVOID lParam);

const int ASCII_LEN = 128;
const int KEYBOARD = 1;
const int LBUTTON = 2;
const int RBUTTON = 3;
const int IDLE = 4;
```

**result**

```
--------------------Configuration: ReadFileTest - Win32 Debug---------- ----------
Compiling...
main.cpp
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.h(20) : error C2065: 'PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.h(20) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'instance'
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.h(20) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.h(20) : error C2182: 'ProcessHook' : illegal use of type 'void'
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.h(20) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.cpp(13) : error C2065: 'TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.cpp(60) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'instance'
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.cpp(60) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.cpp(60) : error C2182: 'ProcessHook' : illegal use of type 'void'
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.cpp(60) : error C2086: 'ProcessHook' : redefinition
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.cpp(60) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.cpp(61) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
c:\users\jasey\windows-program\readfiletest\main.cpp(61) : error C2447: missing function header (old-style formal list?)
执行 cl.exe 时出错.
Creating browse info file...

ReadFileTest.exe - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: What is the reason of still using VC 6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows thread pool, 'PTP\_CALLBACK\_INSTANCE' : undeclared identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033221/windows-thread-pool-ptp-callback-instance-undeclared-identifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API was introduced in Windows Vista. Latest Windows SDK supported in VC 6 is for windows server 2003, it's older than Vista.

Best way to fix is upgrade Visual C++ to some newer version.

Comment: I See!  it required threadpoolapiset.h (include Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows.h). So VC 6.0 not support new SDK. Thanks